# multiply numbers after a string in diferent columns, and then add the results to one column

Tags: bash, awk

Hi I need to multiply numbers after a string in diferent columns, and then add the results to one column

```
value=12 value2=5 value3=2
```

the operation will look something like this, the multiplicator is defined by column index, or if its posible by the string that precedes the number

```
value=12*2 value2=5*4 value3=2*7
value=24 + value2=20 + value3=14
value=58
```

Comment: On SO we encourage users to post their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, please add and let us know then.

Comment: How is the multiplicator defined? By the column index?

Comment: There's so many things that could mean it'll be tough to get an answer without a lot more information.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an index map is provided, which maps the column index to a given multiplier, e.g.

```
 1 -> 2
 2 -> 4 
 3 -> 7
```

try using this script or the following "one-liner" (Maybe not the most elegant code):

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT="value=12 value2=5 value3=2"
m=(2 4 7)

IFS=' ' read -ra IN <<< "$INPUT"
for ((i=0; i<${#IN[@]}; ++i)); do
  tmp=${IN[$i]}
  sum=$((sum + $(awk -F '=' -v m="${m[$i]}" '{print m*$2}' <<< ${tmp##value})))
done
echo $sum
```

"One-liner":

```
awk -F ' ' 'BEGIN {m[1]=2; m[2]=4; m[3]=7;} {for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) {split($(i),a,"="); sum+=m[i] * a[2];}} END { print sum; } ' <<< "value=12 value2=5 value3=2"
```

Inferring, that the first column has multiplier 2 if not specified, and then 
ascending, `num+1` based on the number `num` left to the equation sign, here a quick solution:

```
INPUT="value=12 value2=5 value3=2"
IFS=' ' read -ra IN <<< "$INPUT"
sum=0
for i in "${IN[@]}"; do
  sum=$((sum + $(awk -F '=' '{print (!$1 ? 2 : $1+1) * $2}' <<< ${i##value})))
done
echo $sum
```

Comment: the multiplier is not ascending, could be any number

Comment: Onion layer 1 peeled. Next... Make sure to put all relevant information in your question, not spread out across comments.

Comment: So... you have a map which maps indices of column to multiplier?